# How to separate player characters occupying the same board game space?

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, collision-resolution, board-game

I'm trying to create a 2D "board game" type thing in Unity, and I would like each player to be visible within the same space.

The way I want to do that is by having it so when a player collides with another player, which will happen when it enters the same space, it is pushed away from the other player by a certain amount to make it visible and not completely overlap, because the players use the same sprites and are the same size.

I've tried to do this myself, but I end up pushing both the player I want to stay and the player I want to be pushed, and I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: The way to do what I wanted to do was to just use a script attached to an empty object to check if two players' positions were equal and if they were to use transform.Translate to move one, not 2D physics. I didn't need something more automated than just specifically moving the objects themselves since I only have six players at the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using colliders, use data.

If you have a board (say 12 by 12 squares) make an array[12,12] and store a list of players in each location.

You can then check if the number of players at that array location is >1 and then position your sprites accordingly.

Comment: It sounds like choosing the non-overlapping positions "accordingly" is still something OP needs help with, regardless of how they detect the situation. Do you have any recommendations for a placement algorithm to work with this array?

Comment: I think the issue is the OP is using the physics library to "push" the players apart and getting random results based on velocity and who's doing the pushing?

So his solution is to use data to track the units position in the grid, rather than relying on colliders.

Place sprites in the tile to be visible is trivial - just offset their transform so they appear in the tile how you want them.

Comment: Right. Can you show this trivial step? If OP isn't already doing it that way, then they might not be familiar with how to do it, even if it's simple. That's not an uncommon situation for a beginner to find themselves in, so erring on the side of explaining more can be very helpful to new devs (and attract upvotes for a thorough answer).